# uid-already-exist error when creating a non-existing user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

There is a firebase server-side(firebase functions) code which creates a user if given userId doesn't exist.

It usually works fine, but rarely fails.

```
function createUserIfNotExist(userId, userName) {
    admin.auth().getUser(userId).then(function (userRecord) {
        return userRecord;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return admin.auth().createUser({
            uid: userId,
            displayName: userName,
        })
    })
}
```

When given userId doesn't exist, admin.auth().getUser() throws

```
{ code: 'auth/user-not-found', message: 'There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.' }
```

So admin.auth().createUser() is called in catch clause. But it sometimes fails with following error

```
{ Error: The user with the provided uid already exists.
    at FirebaseAuthError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:104:23)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:128:16)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:399:45
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'auth/uid-already-exists',
     message: 'The user with the provided uid already exists.' } }
```

Is it firebase bug or something is wrong in my code?

Comment: Since UIDs are fairly random, how do you get a UID for a user that doesn't exist yet? I.e. where do these values come from when you invoke `createUserIfNotExist`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the UIDs are generated by 3rd party auth(facebook messenger platform). We use custom authentication.

Answer (score 2):

There don't appear to be a lot of other [documented reasons](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) besides `auth/internal-error` why the call to `getUser()` would fail, but it would be safer to explicitly check for `auth/user-not-found` before requesting creation of a new user:

```
function createUserIfNotExist(userId, userName) {
    admin.auth().getUser(userId).then(function (userRecord) {
        return userRecord;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            return admin.auth().createUser({
                uid: userId,
                displayName: userName,
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Error getting user data:", error);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I didn't include your error.code checking, it always the 'auth/user-not-found' when it is thrown to the catch clause.